# How do I make Automator select a list of files recursively?

Tags: actionscript, automator

I am working on an Automator that needs to open a sequence of files in Photoshop and define them as a pattern (and no, Photoshop Actions will not do it in the way I need it to.) I have the automator application working, but it will not run through the files recursively and instead runs the action on only the first file.

Is there a simple actionScript that can be inserted into the action to run recursively? Or is there a way to use the loop action and select the first file, then have Automator select the next file in sequence?

Currently, my action is in this sequence:

- Open Finder Items: in Photoshop
- Watch Me Do: selects the correct menu item inside PShop and clicks OK
- Close file

Answer (score 0):

It isn't recursive, but you can use the **Dispense Items Incrementally** action from http://automator.us/leopard/downloads/ - it is used with the **Loop** action to step through files one at a time.